# If we apply a magnetic field to a core saturated by a permanent magnet, what will happen?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, superposition

If we apply a magnetic field to a core saturated by permanent magnet, will the magnetic field of the permanent magnet and electromagnet get combined?
I mean to say superposition will be applied? [image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they will add up. They will get stronger if they are pointing in the same direction, and weaker if the electromagnet's magnetic field is pointing oppositely to the permanent magnet's magnetic field.

But the material inside won't get magnetized further. The magnetic field from an electromagnet and a permanent magnet is the same. So if one cannot increase the magnetization further, the other naturally won't as well.

Comment: but if core is saturated

Comment: The thing is that magnetic fields from electromagnet and permanent magnets are the same. So if one cannot, the other won't as well.

Comment: I'll edit my answer because I missed your actual question

Comment: Two permanent magnet make one bigger magnet and so a flux, so what electromagnet and permanent magnet do ?

Comment: A bigger magnet

Comment: Where flux will go in close circuit